# Need a way to synchronize two operations

Tags: c++

I have a class Connection which is a kind of wrapper over Zmq Request/Reply. Using this I will accept requests from client and send the response back. Two functions used to accomplish these are:-

```
void Connection::receiveMessage ()
{
//recv messages over zmq and send it to back-end.
}

void Connection::sendMessage ()
{
//This method would be called by back-end and it will send the message over Zmq.
}
```

Issue facing:-
As zmq request/reply is synchronous operation, I have to send reply ( which I would get from back-end in-response to recvd message ) before receiving new message. In some cases Connection class executes a method on backend object and returns. When back-end is ready with data it would call sendMessage. But here I am again trying to receive message without sending previous response.

Can anyone please help me to ensure that Connection would not enter into recv till it sends response to previous messages.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need Real time transmit. 
Download JRTPLIB's

[Free RTP lib's for C++](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib)